# A C++ code generator from an XML spec

Tags: c++, xml

I'd like to know if there's a tool which allows you to do class definition based on an XML format. I'm not looking for data binding. Anyone can help ?

Thanks

Comment: A short example that illustrates what you are asking about would be a good idea.

Comment: I guess he/she means a tool that can generate a class or set of classes (probably POD structs) from an XML schema.

Comment: I am looking for a tool which lets me defines classes using an XML specification and from it is able to generate all the files and code associate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of two tools both of them are commercial products

http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/

- Is open source GPL - commercial licence is avalable for commercial use
- I think this is/was used by [gSOAP](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/)
- [http://www.artima.com/cppsource/xml_data_binding.html](http://ttp://www.artima.com/cppsource/xml_data_binding.html)

http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/

- don't know any more than the web site

I hope this helps.

Update:

Just found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding#C.2B.2B

Update 2:

This is great, I have been looking for an open source package to do this for ages and your question has just helped my find it:

http://top.touk.pl/confluence/display/xmlbeansxxdoc/Introduction+to+xmlbeansxx
http://top.touk.pl/confluence/download/attachments/458767/Manipulate_XML_Documents_in_CPP_with_xmlbeansxx.pdf

Comment: Hi,

I've already known about codesynthesis, while it does produce C++ code from XML files, it's more a binding of data, than the generation of C++ classes itself. 

I've also known of codealogic, I'm not sure of what it does exactly i was planing on tryin it later this week, you just confirmed tha tI should ^^

I'm happy that we could help each other.

I don't think i explain myself clearly, I am more searching for a tool which would automate the protyping of classes from an XML file that interactimg and manipulating XML with C++.

But the pdf look interesting, thank you :)

Comment: OK I was looking for a code generator for turning an xml schema to a set of value object classes for reading and writing the xml schema because I hate writing dom manipulation code.

Comment: Sorry but it is incorrect to state that "Codesynthesis is/was used by gSOAP". The [gSOAP](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2) XML data bindings tools have been around longer than Codesynthesis. In fact, gSOAP provides an XML data binding for C and C++ (classes etc). The gSOAP tools are extensively used in industry as it complies with industry standards and the W3C XML data bindings working group recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

When I had this problem a few years back, I wrote a Python tool to execute Python code embedded in text files so that I could generate C++ code with Python inside the C++: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/

Answer (score 0):

YACC or BISON may be what you are after.

Comment: It's true that it would invlove some parsing but I XML parsing don't require the direct use of YACC or BISON

Answer (score 0):

Are [UML Class Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) what you are looking for?

Comment: No but I know tools which can generate code from UML, that could solve my problem if I found myself being more productive typing that drawings schema.