# XML DataBinding and C++ code generator

Tags: c++, data-binding, xsd, code-generation

there's already a topic about it but I haven't found a helpful answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316320/a-c-code-generator-from-an-xml-spec).

I'm looking for a library or a tool which can read xsd grammar and then can write a corresponding object in c++ (.hpp, .cpp,...).

Except codesynthsesis, does someone know much about it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge list of data binding code generators on http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema , just search the site for `C++`. Also please describe in detail why the answers on [A C++ code generator from an XML spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316320/a-c-code-generator-from-an-xml-spec) weren't helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'm studying w3c tools about xsd right now. There's many things. 
This article didn't help me because, I already know code synthesis (it's under GPL Licence, it's not exactly what I want so I'm looking for alternatives), I coulndt test xmlplus because I'm not on Linux right now and GLSgen, I don't figure out how to make it work, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The information at http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm can be very helpful. But beware that the list of tools on that web site is slowly getting out of date. The W3C list of data binding tools http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema is outdated (the last update was way back in 2009).

I'm using the [GSOAP](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2) toolkit from SourceForge for all of my XML C++ projects. Also works for plain C. It binds C/C++ to XML schemas automatically and is fully compliant with industry standards for XML, WSDL, SOAP, REST, XML-RPC, JSON, and WS-* protocols.

GSOAP is actively maintained, easy to use, and pretty efficient too.