# seeking a code generator to create XML read-in routine from abstract document description

Tags: c, xml, xsd, code-generation

Writing a XML read-in routine in C, using libxml, is tedious, especially if you want to do it cleanly, with checks and error messages for missing nodes or invalid contents; and the resulting code is lengthy, noisy, boring.

Therefore I wonder whether there isn't a tool to automatically generate a read-in routine from an abstract description of admissible XML documents (something like XML schema, I guess).

I am aware of this [A C++ code generator from an XML spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316320/) and this http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/, apparently solving the problem for C++, but I really need to produce C code.

Comment: Why can't you link the generated C++ code to your C code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commercial product that produces C code from XML Schema: [XBinder](http://www.obj-sys.com/xbinder.shtml) (I currently work for this company.)