# Generate C++ function automatically

Tags: c++, code-generation

I am looking for an automated solution to generate C++ source with some function prototypes from provided configuration. The input is something similar below in an xml

```
<xml>
   <function="myfunction1" params="arg1" type="integer" return="void">
</xml>
```

the automatic code generator shall produce code as below

```
void myfunction1(int arg1)
{
    //your logic here
}
```

How this can be achieved generally ? Is there any C++ automatic code generation framework already available which can be slightly modified to achieve above ?

Comment: These kind of questions (_"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"_)  are off topic.

Comment: This has been previously asked : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321004/8881651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A C++ code generator from an XML spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316320/a-c-code-generator-from-an-xml-spec)

Comment: Not sure what you expected from framework... once you parse your xml, is it just writing "return function(type params)" ?